# Drupal 7 Commerce Price field not available to views

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal 7.14, Commerce 7.x 1.3 and Views 7.x 3.3
I have created several products and also the corresponding content. Fields in the product type are the default fields - Product SKU, Title, Price and Status. The content type upon which the related content is based contains some extra fields - image, product reference, author and type.
The products display singly perfectly with all the fields (image, Body, price, author, add to cart button and type).
If I create a view to display this content the available fields do not contain the price field. All the others, however, display correctly.
Why is the price field missing?
Would be most grateful for anyone's help.

Answer (score 6):

You should add **Content: Product** as a relation to this view. Then you'll have all the fields from the product available in the view.

Comment: Hi Marius,Thanks for you rapid reply. Have installed the Relation module and set permissions. I gather I need to create a relation type. When I do this it appears I have to define a Source Bundle. Can you guide me on this?

Comment: Have now noticed that, in Source Bundle and under Node there is Publications Display which is the name of the content type I have defined. Should I salect that?

Comment: you don't need the relation module. just go to the view in the advanced section (right hand side) and add a relation there

Comment: Hi Marius, now realise what you meant. Have set (under Advanced) Relationships to Content: Publication Reference and the field is now available.

Comment: Its really a useful answer @MariusIlie

Comment: @MariusIlie It works fine when I am loged in but when I logged out my view is not displaying any field, any idea ??

Comment: Well I have checked view any products of any type, this have resolved the display issue for now but looking for a better way.